# C++ Overloading operator= to get right and left hand overload

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is more of an, I always wanted to know scenario. In the following code, `tclass` has one `int` as a private member. You can see the `operator=` overload. If you look at the main code, you see the `bbb` which is a `tclass` object. in one line 
`bbb = 7;`

We use the operator to take a `tclass` object and through the `operator=` I am able to pass a right hand `int`, thus filling the `my_intvalue` in the `tclass bbb;`

Much the same as you would expect if you had an `int yyy = 5`, the right hand 5 is passed into the `yyy`'s value.

So, how do you overload `tclass` to get what I have in `main()` but it is commented out because I could not figure it out

`yyy = bbb;`

where the value of `my_intvalue` in `bbb` is passed to `yyy`, an `int`;

Main code Testing.cpp

```
// Testing.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tclass.h"



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    tclass bbb;
    int yyy = 5;
    bbb = 7;

    //yyy = bbb;

    return 0;
}
```

tclass.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef TCLASS_H
#define TCLASS_H

class tclass
{
private:
    int my_intvalue;
public:
    tclass()
    {
        my_intvalue = 0;
    }
    ~tclass()
    {
    }
    tclass& operator= (int rhs)//right hand
    {
        this->my_intvalue = rhs;
        return *this;
    }

    private:
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot pass an object to an `int`, unless you define a [conversion-to-int operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) for your class `tclass`,

```
class tclass
{
// previous stuff
    operator int() // conversion to int operator
    {
        return my_intvalue;
    }
};
```

Then you can use it like

```
int yyy = bbb; // invokes the bbb.operator int()
```

As @Yongwei Wu mentioned in the comment below, sometimes conversion operators may introduce subtle "issues" in your code, since a conversion will be performed when you least expect it. To avoid such scenarios, you can either mark the operator `explicit` (C++11 or later), such as

```
explicit operator int() { return my_intvalue;}
```

and then you'll have to explicitly say that you want a conversion

```
int yyy = static_cast<int>(bbb); // int yyy = bbb won't compile anymore
```

or use a different "conversion" function

```
int to_int() { return my_intvalue;}
```

and call it like

```
int yyy = bbb.to_int();
```

Comment: It is better to avoid automatic conversions, in cases where it can surprise you. I think the general recommendation is that you should implement a `to_int()` member, and use `yyy = bbb.to_int()` explicitly. Scott Meyers has a specific item called "Be wary of user-defined conversion functions".

Comment: @YongweiWu true, same can be said about non-explicit conversion constructors. However I think it's good to make OP aware of them. And if you want to be safe, one can now (C++11 or later) declare the conversion operator `explicit`, and a `static_cast<int>(bbb)` will then be necessary.